# How to get chekbox values on Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i'm at linking my form data to my mysql database server so far so good i have a  little problems here

my prcoes.php. code :

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db (DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' / mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['name'];
$value2 = $_POST['surname'];
$value3 = $_POST['email'];
$value4 = $_POST['phone'];
$value4 = $_POST['activity'];
$value5 = $_POST['ltype'];
```

With checkboxes `$_POST['ltype'];`i get only `Array` on Mysql as result ?
I get the right values with this code by sending form data to my email :

```
'LType : ' . implode(',', $_POST['ltype']). "\n" .
```

Any help will be welcomed , thanks in  advance
 Update here my chekbox code :

```
                                 <div class="thumb1" >
                                        <label for="word"  ><img class="img" src="images/my1.jpg"  /></label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]" id="word" value="word"  /><hr> <p><strong>Word Mark Logo</strong></p>
                                   </div>

                                   <div class="thumb1" >
                                         <label for="letter"><img class="img" src="images/my2.jpg"  /></label>
                                         <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]"  id="letter" value="letter" /><hr> <p><strong>Letter Mark Logo</strong></p>
                                   </div>

                                   <div class="thumb1">
                                          <label for="emblerm"><img class="img" src="images/my3.jpg"  /></label>
                                          <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]" id="emblerm" value="emblerm" /><hr> <p><strong>Emblerm Logo</strong></p>
                                   </div>
```

Comment: No idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: your `<select>` is named `industry`, but nowhere do you try to use `$_POST['industry']`

Comment: i'm not getting values from my drop down list  when data submitted on mysql @RiggsFolly

Comment: @Marc B oh man i have overseen that part i was so busy those days thanks a lot the dropdown list got fixed

Comment: @NewLogo Little tip dude, save your db select/connect as a seperate page (lets call it connect.php) then use include("connect.php") every page. Less code to write is all :)

Comment: @Ryan McKenna thanks for your tip dude it is a very good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you:

```
$value5 = implode(',', $_POST['ltype']);
```

if you want the array back just explode the database value.

Comment: i get "  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in " with this @Martijn

Comment: please var_dump($_POST['ltype']); for me?

Comment: "Fatal error: Function name must be a string in " @Martijn          with 'var_dump($_POST['ltype']);'

Comment: Why you are getting the fatal error i don't understand. But did you submit a value for ltype? try: $value5 = (!empty($_POST['ltype'])) ? implode(',', $_POST['ltype']) : '';

Comment: yet it's working my mistake was i just changed the codes and refreshed the page in the process.php and it resulted as null values after the first submit. thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you define the checkbox if

```
<form action='XXX.php' method='POST'>
  Football: <input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="football"  />
  Baseball: <input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="baseball"  />
</form>
```

And on the XXX.php it return as array

```
if ( $_POST['sports'] ) {
  $arySports = $_POST['sports'];
  foreach( $arySports AS $value ) {
    echo $value ."<br>";
  }
}
```

If you did

```
Subscribe Now <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" />
```

And on the XXX.php it return as on

If you did

```
Subscribe Now <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="now" />
```

Then it return string "now".  So try with this and see what you want for your checkbox

```
<form action="XXX.php" method="POST">
  <input type='checkbox' name='A'/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='B' value='this is array'/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='B' value='the second one'/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='C[]' value='A'/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='C[]' value='B'/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='C[]' value='C'/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='D' value='string'/>
</form>
```

on the XXX.php do

```
print_r( $_POST['A'] );
echo "<br>";
print_r( $_POST['B'] );
echo "<br>";
print_r( $_POST['C'] );
echo "<br>";
print_r( $_POST['D'] );
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: @NewLogo : if the code helps you , you are supposed to upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Yes i upvote this right now but i still haven't solve my problem @hitesh

Comment: @NewLogo: Saw your update, you should get an Array from the $_POST['ltype']. So process $value5 as Array, not sure what kind error you get from foreach, only if there is no option checked, then it will crash the foreach. so add if the ltype exists and do the foreach.

Comment: @Li Kia Chiu i wrote this $value5 =  $aryltype = $_POST['ltype'];
foreach( $aryltype AS $value ) {
  echo $value ."<br>";
}; with this code i get "  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in " correct me if am wrong thanks .

Comment: try use print_r( $aryltype ) and see what's the print out.